# "Re-standardization" of variables in factor analyses?

Tags: correlation, covariance, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable

I'm currently reading the textbook, "Latent Variable Models" by JC Loehlin and AA Beaujean.

Today I've encountered the following regarding whether to analyze covariances or correlations in latent variable analyses.

> One further consideration, of minor concern in the present study, will
> sometimes prove decisive.
>
> If the observed variables' variances change markedly over time, one should be wary of analyzing correlations ***because this in effect re-standardizes all variables
> at each time period***.
>
> Some alternative solutions that retain the advantages of
> standardization for comparing variables are ***to standardize the variables once***, either for the initial
> period or across all time periods combined, and compute and ***analyze the covariance matrix of these standardized variables***.

First, I understand that I shall not use correlations when there's a significant variance gap between observed variables,

especially when comparing across differing populations because then the standardized regression coefficient

would be very difficult to interpret.

But what do you mean by "re-standardizes all variables at each time period"?

I'm completely lost here, having read the same phrase over and over to no avail.

Second, why analyzing the covariance matrix of standardized variables does good?

I believe, by definition, covariances of standardized variables are equal to correlations.

Then why does it make a difference?

I really appreciate any help!!!

Comment: I guessed that the textbook is "Latent Variables Models" by JC Loehlin and AA Beaujean. If I guessed wrong, please update the question with the correct author information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what do you mean by "re-standardizes all variables at each time period"?

Imagine the data in long format, with all observations across all occasions (from all groups) in a single column. "To standardize the variables once" means to divide all observations by the same *SD*, which provides a single "unit of measurement" for all scaled variables and clarifies the interpretation of standardized coefficients.  The common *SD* could be the grand *SD* across occasions, or the *SD* at the first occasion, or any other meaningful values with which to scale the data and interpret coefficients in those units.

"Re-standardizing" at each occasion divides by the time-specific *SD*, which in long-format data would be analogous to cluster-mean-centering (or standardizing within cluster) rather than grand-mean-centering/scaling.  This makes each occasion have different units, to the degree that *SD*s differ across occasions.

> why analyzing the covariance matrix of standardized variables does good?

You can't trust your *SE*s and tests unless residual variances are constrained to reflect the fact that each variance = 1 by definition (i.e., it is fixed, not a quantity to estimate).

Cudeck, R. (1989). Analysis of correlation matrices using covariance structure models. *Psychological Bulletin, 105*(2), 317–327. https://doi.org/10.1037/0033-2909.105.2.317

In the case of comparing coefficients across populations or repeated measures, even the point estimates are of dubious value when the same variable is expressed in different units across those populations or repeated measures.

> I believe, by definition, covariances of standardized variables are equal to correlations.

Not if you standardize by scaling all variables by a common *SD* instead of an occasion-specific *SD*.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!